# Colorbox is not loading ajax content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, google-chrome, jquery, colorbox

```
<a href="/Search/ReadChain/?CategoryID=123&ParentID=5587&LogDate=10/12/2012" class="ReadChainDL">Read Chain</a>

$(".ReadChainDL").colorbox();
```

When I click the Read Chain it runs the ajax and loads the colorbox, but the colorbox is blank!  I can confirm that ajax is running and pulling the correct content via firebug.  It's just not populating the generated ajax content into the colorbox.  I've confirmed via firebug that colorbox is blank.

I've tried it in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

It's got to be the URL; your code works fine. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/HP8tN/

I think there are two main possibilities:

- There's no filename, so maybe Colorbox doesn't know what content type to use. Or maybe the URL is wrong, or the target has the wrong content type. I think this is the most likely option. Try `$(".ReadChainDL").colorbox({photo: true});` if it's a photo. Otherwise, [check out the Content Type section in the documentation.](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)
- Colorbox is supposed to figure out whether you've passed it a URL or a jQuery-style XPath selector. The `10/12/2012` could be messing up whatever logic it uses to recognize a URL. This seems unlikely, since you've confirmed that something is coming back, but it's worth a try. Try `10%2F12%2F2012` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the content that is being returned by the ajax call?  jQuery may not be able to append it to your document if there are issues with it being invalid or malformed.

Try validating your content.